# Ambiguity between default-initialization and value-initialization

Tags: c++, initialization, value-initialization, default-initialization

I found many articles explaining the difference between "default-initialization and value-initialization" but in fact I didn't understand clearly.

Here's an example:

```
class A{
   public:
      int x;
};


int main(){
    A a;// default initialization so x has undefined value.
    A b = A(); // value initialization so x is a scalar thus it is value initialized to 0

}
```

Above it is OK as I guess but here:

```
int value = 4; // is this considered a value-initialization?
```

Please help me understand the major differences between the two forms of initializations.

Comment: [Looks like Copy Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) Here's [another link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) that (roughly) covers all of the different types of initialization you could run across

Comment: `A a;` does not have default initialisation. I thought `A a1{};` default initialises, and `A a2{1};` value initialises, and `A a3{a2};` copy initialises, although the above link states that `A a1{};` is value initialised, so perhaps I'm just wrong.

Comment: @Tas Yes you're just wrong. `A a1{};` is value initialization, and `A a2{1};` and `A a3{a2};` are direct initialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A a;` is [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization), as the effect the default constructor of `A` is used for initialization. Since the [implicitly-generated default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) of `A` does nothing, `a.x` has indeterminate value.

`A()` is [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization),

> if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) and then it is [default-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) if it has a non-trivial default constructor;

Note the difference with [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization), `A` has an implicitly-defined default constructor, and the object is [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization); so the data memeber `x` of the temporary object `A()` will be initialized to `0`.

`A b = A();` is [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), in concept `b` is initialized from the temporary object `A()`, so `b.x` will be initialized to `0` too. Note that because of [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), since C++17 `b` is guaranteed to be [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) directly; the copy/move construction is omitted.

`int value = 4;` is [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) too. `value` will be initialized to `4`.

Comment: Do you mean if class `A` has a user-defined constructor then writing `A a;` is not default-initialization?

Comment: @RamiYen No, `A a;` is still default initialization. And `A()` is still value initialization. But the effect of value initialization will change to be same as default initialization. Both the effect will be initialize the object by the user-defined default constructor, zero initialization doesn't participate in again.